# Adding contact information to new div using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, dynamic

I am working on a project where the user enters first name, last name, and a brief description. After hitting the submit button the first and last name will transfer to a new div below. If you click on the the first and last name the new div will flip and show the description the user wrote for himself/herself. If the user clicks on the description the card flips back to first and last name.
  I am able to get the first and last name to transfer after hitting the submit button. However, I am having difficulty getting the card with the first and last name to flip and show the description information and flipping back to the first and last name. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  alert('jQuery activated');

  $('form').submit(function() {
    alert('form submitted');
    $('#contact_card').append("<div class='person'><h4>" + $('#first_name').val() + " " + $('#last_name').val() + "</h4><p>Click for more details</p></div>");

    return false;


  });

  $(document).on('click', '.person', function() {
    alert('user clicked');
    $(this).children().toggle('slow');




  });

});
```

```css
* {
  font-family: "Tahoma";
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
#container {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 750px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
#left,
form {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 500px;
}
#left form h3 {
  margin: 0px 0px 13px 0px;
}
.person {
  border: 8px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<head>
  <title>Advanced jQuery Assignment III: Contact Card</title>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="left">
      <form>
        <br>First Name:
        <input class="user_input" type="text" id="first_name">
        <br>
        <br>Last Name:
        <input class="user_input" type="text" id="last_name">
        <br>
        <label for="description"></label>
        <textarea name="description" type="text" id="description" cols="50" rows="10">Enter Description</textarea>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Add User">
      </form>
    </div>
    <!-- end of left -->

    <div id="bottom">
      <div id="contact_card">

      </div>
      <!-- end of contact_card -->
    </div>
    <!-- end of bottom -->
  </div>
  <!-- end of container -->
```

Comment: you did not add your description to the page

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13553671/flip-between-two-divs-when-clicking-on-the-divs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So add the description to the `contact_card` in a hidden `p`. Then when you click on class `person` just toggle the `p` children.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('form').submit(function() {
    $('#contact_card').append("<div class='person'><h4>" + $('#first_name').val() + " " + $('#last_name').val() + "</h4><p>Click for more details</p><p hidden>"+$('#description').val()+"</p></div>");

    return false;
  });

  $(document).on('click', '.person', function() {
    $(this).children('p').toggle('slow');
  });

});
```

```css
* {
  font-family: "Tahoma";
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
#container {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 750px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
#left,
form {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 500px;
}
#left form h3 {
  margin: 0px 0px 13px 0px;
}
.person {
  border: 8px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<head>
  <title>Advanced jQuery Assignment III: Contact Card</title>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="left">
      <form>
        <br>First Name:
        <input class="user_input" type="text" id="first_name">
        <br>
        <br>Last Name:
        <input class="user_input" type="text" id="last_name">
        <br>
        <label for="description"></label>
        <textarea name="description" type="text" id="description" cols="50" rows="10">Enter Description</textarea>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Add User">
      </form>
    </div>
    <!-- end of left -->

    <div id="bottom">
      <div id="contact_card">

      </div>
      <!-- end of contact_card -->
    </div>
    <!-- end of bottom -->
  </div>
  <!-- end of container -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I've detailed how you can go about doing this in the below code. There are multiple ways you can go about doing this. In my example, I decided to swap the name for the description and vice versa upon clicking by removing and adding the elements to/from the DOM.

First I create two functions: one to create the name view and the other to create the description view

```
        // Generates view for name
         var getNameView = function(user) { 
            return $("<div class='person'><div><h4>" + user.first_name + " " + user.last_name + "</h4><p>Click for more details</p></div></div>")
        };

        // Generates view for description
        var getDescriptionView = function(user) { 
            return $("<div class='person'><div><h4>" + user.description + " " + "</h4><p>Click to go back</p></div></div>")
        };
```

Next we alter the handler for the form submit to grab the details of all of the fields, store it as an object and clear the fields for the next entry. This function will also add the element to the page.

```
        // Listen for form submit
        $('form').submit(function() {

            // Stores details of user being added
            var user = {
                first_name: $('#first_name').val(),
                last_name: $('#last_name').val(),
                description: $("#description").val()
            }; 

            // Add user to list of users
            users.push(user);

            // Append name view for user
            $('#contact_card').append(getNameView(user))

            // Clear fields 
            $("#first_name").val("")
            $("#last_name").val("")
            $("#description").val("")

            return false

        });
```

Lastly, we need to handle the swapping of content between the name and description upon clicking on the person element. To do this we will first close the element being clicked on and then based on a class (in this case "description") we will determine which view to show for that element.

```
        $(document).on('click', '.person', function(){

            // Store a reference to the element for the person clicked on
            var $person = $(this)

            // Hide the contents of the person element before swapping views
            $person.children().slideUp('slow', function() { 

                // Determine whether we should show the description.
                // We'll use a class on the person element to determine this.
                if ($person.hasClass("description")) { 
                    $person.removeClass("description");
                    $person.html(getNameView(users[$person.index()]).children())
                    $person.children().slideDown('slow');
                }
                else { 
                    $person.addClass("description");
                    $person.html(getDescriptionView(users[$person.index()]).children())
                    $person.children().slideDown('slow');
                }
            }); 


         });
```

Here is the complete code that you'll be able to run

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Advanced jQuery Assignment III: Contact Card</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js" integrity="sha256-iT6Q9iMJYuQiMWNd9lDyBUStIq/8PuOW33aOqmvFpqI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){ 

        // Used to keep track of users being added
        // stores details of user as object
        var users = []; 

        // Generates view for name
         var getNameView = function(user) { 
            return $("<div class='person'><div><h4>" + user.first_name + " " + user.last_name + "</h4><p>Click for more details</p></div></div>")
        };

        // Generates view for description
        var getDescriptionView = function(user) { 
            return $("<div class='person'><div><h4>" + user.description + " " + "</h4><p>Click to go back</p></div></div>")
        };


        // Listen for form submit
        $('form').submit(function() {

            // Stores details of user being added
            var user = {
                first_name: $('#first_name').val(),
                last_name: $('#last_name').val(),
                description: $("#description").val()
            }; 

            // Add user to list of users
            users.push(user);

            // Append name view for user
            $('#contact_card').append(getNameView(user))

            // Clear fields 
            $("#first_name").val("")
            $("#last_name").val("")
            $("#description").val("")

            return false

        }); 


        $(document).on('click', '.person', function(){

            // Store a reference to the element for the person clicked on
            var $person = $(this)

            // Hide the contents of the person element before swapping views
            $person.children().slideUp('slow', function() { 

                // Determine whether we should show the description.
                // We'll use a class on the person element to determine this.
                if ($person.hasClass("description")) { 
                    $person.removeClass("description");
                    $person.html(getNameView(users[$person.index()]).children())
                    $person.children().slideDown('slow');
                }
                else { 
                    $person.addClass("description");
                    $person.html(getDescriptionView(users[$person.index()]).children())
                    $person.children().slideDown('slow');
                }
            }); 


         });

    });

</script>
<style>
    * {
        font-family: "Tahoma";
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }

    #container {
        width: 1000px;
        height: 750px;
        margin: 0px auto;
    }

    #left, form {
        display: inline-block;
        max-width: 500px;
    }

    #left form h3 {
        margin: 0px 0px 13px 0px;
    }

    .person {
        border: 8px solid red;
        margin: 1rem 0;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id ="left">
        <form>
            <br>First Name:
            <input class="user_input" type="text" id="first_name">
            <br>
            <br>Last Name:
            <input class="user_input" type="text" id="last_name">
            <br>
            <label for="description"></label>
            <textarea name="description" type="text" id="description" cols="50" rows="10" placeholder="Enter description"></textarea>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Add User">
        </form>
    </div> <!-- end of left -->

    <div id="bottom">
        <div id="contact_card">

        </div> <!-- end of contact_card -->
    </div> <!-- end of bottom -->
</div>  <!-- end of container -->
```